# Loop through both date and time in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I try to google but I cannot find any solution which can help me.

I have interval of 15 minute and I need to loop through whole week with 15 minute interval.

Date Interval can be any.

What I try is

```js
var array = [{x:'Thu Jul 27 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)',y:1},
      {x:'Thu Jul 21 2017 01:10:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)',y:5},
      {x:'Thu Jul 21 2017 01:15:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)',y:3},
    ...
      {x:'Thu Jul 27 2017 23:55:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)',y:8},
    ];
    var interval = 900000;

    for(var i = 0; i < maxArray.length; i++) { //loop through the existing date object array
              millisecArray.push(maxArray[i]['x'].getTime()); //and push its millisec value into the new array
            }

            var startObj = new Date('2017-07-17 01:00:00');
            var endObj = new Date('2017-07-27 23:55:00');

            var start = startObj.getTime(); //gets the time in millisecs
            var end = endObj.getTime(); //gets the time in millisecs

            var newDateObj = new Date();
            //keep looping until current is 15 minutes smaller than end
            for(var current = start; current < end; current = current + interval){ 
              if( !lookup( current , millisecArray ) ) {
                console.log(new Date(current));//@TODO will give me only time but not date.
              }
            }

            function lookup( name,arr ) {
              for(var j = 0; i < arr.length; j++) {
                if( arr[ j ] === name )
                  return true;
              }
              return false;
            }
```

Comment: Its unclear what you want and your code isnt working / complete

Comment: Yeah... as Jonas said, it's unclear what you want. The inner for loop is correct and is looping between the 2 dates in 15 minutes interval, as it seems you want

Comment: You can use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to manipulate time. It's an external library (not included in jQuery), which is why I'm posting this as a comment and not an answer, but they'll manage daylight saving time, day of week, day of month, etc. Fantastic, simple, well-documented library. Here's the docs to 'add' time (in any increment you want) https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/

Comment: @dev , my answer is helpful to you?

Comment: Sorry guys I was in holiday. I will go thru in a while and response you all. Thanks for all responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with using a `moment.js` library , here is one example how to add `15 minute` into the date.

```js
 var startObj = moment('2017-07-17 01:00:00');
 var endObj = moment('2017-07-27 23:55:00');
 
 for(var current = startObj; current < endObj;current=startObj.add(15,'minute'))
 {
    console.log(current);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Hope this example help to solve your problem.

Comment: Its works fine for me. I have one more question how can I sort this result with date?